# phpmysql query for oncology assesment tool

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have the following tables in my mysql databases. I am trying to create an application that can virtually asses if someone may be developing cancer of the oesophagus.
The aim of this application is to help people in early detection to screen for cancer because 99% of patinets i have been with in all hospitals here in Kenya come at the late rstages of cancer when we can do nothing to revive them simply because they lack information about cancer.The symptoms i have included in this question are to help me understand relational databases so that i can apply it in the real application.The risk factors and symptoms for the cancers that i want to include have been worked on by my fellow medics

```
#tblsymptoms - holds all symptoms
######################################
symptomID  | symptom    
-------------------------------------
1            Mass in the throat        
2            Difficulty in swallowing   
3            Lost weight lately
4            Heartburn
5            Hoarse-sounding cough
6            Vomit blood


#tblresponse - holds all responses
######################################
responseID  | response   
-----------------------------------------------------
1            Your symptoms suggest you have a problem       
2            You may be having Oesophageal carcinoma  
3            You dont have a throat carcinoma

#tblrelation - holds relation between response and symptoms
######################################
relationID  | responseID | symptomID
-----------------------------
       1         1          3
       2         1          4
       3         1          5
       4         2          1
       5         2          2
       6         2          3
       7         2          2
       8         2          5
       9         2          6
       10        3          3
       11        3          4
```

I want to use check boxes in the html form to query the database and here is the code for the form:

```
<form method="post" action="process.php">
<INPUT TYPE=CHECKBOX NAME="option[]" VALUE="Difficulty in swallowing" id="">Difficulty in swallowing<br>
<INPUT TYPE=CHECKBOX NAME="option[]" VALUE="Difficulty in swallowing" id="">Difficulty in swallowing<br>
<INPUT TYPE=CHECKBOX NAME="option[]" VALUE="Lost weight lately" id="">Lost weight lately<br>
<INPUT TYPE=CHECKBOX NAME="option[]" VALUE="Heartburn" id="">Heartburn<br>
<INPUT TYPE=CHECKBOX NAME="option[]" VALUE="Hoarse-sounding cough" id="">Hoarse-sounding cough<br>
<INPUT TYPE=CHECKBOX NAME="option[]" VALUE="Vomit blood" id="">Vomit blood<br>
<input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Diagnose me" />
</form>
```

Now, Just in case someone has selected: `Lost weight lately and Heartburn` the script should fetch data from tblResponse>>>responseID=1 and display to the user:

```
Your symptoms suggest you have a problem.
```

Anyone with an idea on code that i should add to the html form with check boxes to query the database?

Comment: . . was there a problem with my previous answer, apart from all the comments?

Comment: +1 for honorable endeavor. -1 for apparently asking the same queston twice.

Comment: I do also posted correct query with demo, have a look at them before duplicating the question!

Comment: Gordon Linoff: i need to have a look at your Data Mining Book on an automated assistant for helping doctors diagnose breast cancer you were talking about.

Comment: Akam: can you create a php code to query if the user selected 1,2,3,4,5 and 6

Answer (score 0):

This is a very broad question. The basic elements of the answer are easy. Your code for querying the database goes in `process.php`. What you want to do is connect to the database, get your `$_POST` variables from the form, and then query the database using a SQL query. However, there are a number of issues based on your question that seem out of whack. For starters, you need to have the name attribute in each of your checkbox INPUTS equal a unique value. That's how you will get them from `$_POST` in your php script. Second, you provided no code at all from `process.php`, so its hard to know what you've tried. Third, your tables don't seem to totally make sense. It's not clear how the relationship table is supposed to work, not to mention, you have a "4" in the "response ID" column, but you don't have an actual response with an ID of 4 in the Response table. You will probably get better results asking questions here if you try to narrow your inquiry.

Comment: i am trying to find solutions on how to make a process.php code...and sorry, i have corrected the table. so basically what is the easiest way to get the query working